# VBA Timestamp executing first instance but not second

Tags: excel, vba, timestamp

I have a large data set with a number of different columns to update. I am trying to create a way to timestamp a date/time as to when the last time a column was updated. I need to do this for 4 separate instances.

The issue i am having is that it seems to work fine for the first instance of the VBA but then wont execute on another column regardless. Please see my full code sample below:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim myTableRange1 As Range
Dim myDateTimeRange1 As Range
Dim myUpdatedrange1 As Range

Set myTableRange1 = Range("S:S")

If Intersect(Target, myTableRange1) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Set myDateTimeRange1 = Range("A" & Target.Row)
Set myUpdatedrange1 = Range("X" & Target.Row)


If myDateTimeRange1.Value = "" Then
    myDateTimeRange1.Value = Now

End If
myUpdatedrange1.Value = Now

End Sub

Sub Worksheet_Change2(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim myTableRange2 As Range
Dim myDateTimeRange2 As Range
Dim myUpdatedrange2 As Range

Set myTableRange2 = Range("T:T")

If Intersect(Target, myTableRange2) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Set myDateTimeRange2 = Range("zz" & Target.Row)
Set myUpdatedrange2 = Range("Y" & Target.Row)


If myDateTimeRange2.Value = "" Then
    myDateTimeRange2.Value = Now

End If
myUpdatedrange2.Value = Now

End Sub
```

****UPDATE****

I have also tried to merge this code together like below:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim myTableRange1 As Range
Dim myDateTimeRange1 As Range
Dim myUpdatedrange1 As Range
Dim myTableRange2 As Range
Dim myDateTimeRange2 As Range
Dim myUpdatedrange2 As Range

Set myTableRange1 = Range("S:S")
Set myTableRange2 = Range("T:T")

If Intersect(Target, myTableRange1) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
If Intersect(Target, myTableRange2) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Set myDateTimeRange1 = Range("A" & Target.Row)
Set myUpdatedrange1 = Range("X" & Target.Row)
Set myDateTimeRange2 = Range("zz" & Target.Row)
Set myUpdatedrange2 = Range("Y" & Target.Row)


If myDateTimeRange1.Value = "" Then
    myDateTimeRange1.Value = Now
If myDateTimeRange2.Value = "" Then
    myDateTimeRange2.Value = Now

End If
myUpdatedrange1.Value = Now
End If
myUpdatedrange2.Value = Now

End Sub
```

And this resulted in neither working.

I am new to VBA so Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: You can only have one `Worksheet_Change` event for each sheet so you need to combine your code.

Comment: Thank you would it be written then along the lines of `Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim myTableRange1 As Range
Dim myTableRange2 As Range`

And then repeat this for each section?

Comment: Yes and you have to change the intersect line to cover both columns and then have one block dependent on which column changed. If Target is multiple cells you will need to loop through the range (or can exclude that in the code `if target.count>1 then exit sub`).

Comment: @SJR I have updated my question with the ammended code this resulted in nothing producing

Comment: Use this cool [indenter](http://rubberduckvba.com/indentation) and you'll see that your `End If`s aren't all in the right place.

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this (in outline form) so as not to discount changes to a single column.

If you changed T only, your updated code would exit before getting to the relevant bit of code.

If you changed S and T, it would only do the S bit.

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim myTableRange1 As Range
Dim myDateTimeRange1 As Range
Dim myUpdatedrange1 As Range
Dim myTableRange2 As Range
Dim myDateTimeRange2 As Range
Dim myUpdatedrange2 As Range

Set myTableRange1 = Range("S:S")
Set myTableRange2 = Range("T:T")

If Not Intersect(Target, myTableRange1) Is Nothing Then
    'your column S code

ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, myTableRange2) Is Nothing Then
    'your column T code

End If

End Sub
```